# index.html should clear session/cookies

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have the following frame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.eggsandbacon.jquery.js"></iframe>
```

Inside my `index.html` document.

I want to reset and delete all the session cookies after each user have played my jQuery game. Is there any way to do this without changing something in the game? The game is on another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't touch cookies on [a different origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).